# Check if user has signed in using Password Authentication in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, password-protection

I am using password authentication of `firebase`. I have registered my app with `firebase` and enabled the email/password authentication.In my `MainActivity`,i have signup and login button which opens signup and login activity.If there is a successfully signup/login, i am redirecting the user to `ImageActivity`. Up to this it works fine.When the user is in `ImageActivity` and if he/she press back button,the app should close but instead i am taken to the Login/Signup Activity. I have already written the following code in `onCreate` of both Login/Signup Activity.

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ImageActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
```

I have wrote this code in my `MainActivity` `onCreate` also.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To prevent this problem you can do couple of things**

First: When you start ImageActivity you clear the back stack and you should declare that Image Activity as a new Task. To do that you should write following code in LoginActivity or SignupActivity

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ImageActivity.class); // Change LoginActivity to SignupActivity if you are calling ImageActivity from SignupActivity
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
    }
```

> If you start Signup/LoginActivity from MainActivity, make sure that
>   you do the same when you start LoginActivity and SignupActivity from
>   MainActivity.

After doing that implement onBackPressed on your ImageActivity class. And call finish() in onBackPressed. The code is below

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

*After doing this I hope that your problem will be solved.*

Comment: I just added this line intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  It works.Thanks alot

Comment: I am very happy to helping you!

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
if (password.length() < 6) {                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));} else {Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}} else {Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);startActivityForResult(intent,1);finish();}}});

Comment: You must check **password.length()** before set it to **auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)**

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because i copy pasted the code from androidhive